# yael mex files for windows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mex

I have a problem in using yael library in matlab.

Yael library has some functions like **yael_ivf** that has written in c.

I'm using mex command in matlab to create mex file but there are some error like this -->

> Error using mex    Creating library yael_ivf.lib and object
>   yael_ivf.exp    yael_ivf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol _ivf_new    referenced in function _mexFunction    yael_ivf.obj
>   : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ivf_delete    referenced
>   in function _mexFunction

Please help me to mex them or if link me to Yael windows mex file.

This is yael library link: [gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=2151](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=2151) in this page there are some links to download, for mac, for linux and [windows](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/34217/yael_v438.tar.gz). The Yael library for linux and mac contain mex files but unfortunately there aren't any mex file in windows link.

If you download [windows yael library (third link)](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/34217/yael_v438.tar.gz), in matlab folder, when you run make.m, mex files must create. but there are some errors for me.

Comment: Most of us have probably never used the "Yael" library before.  Please provide a link or something where you have found this library.  Also please provide **all commands** to help us reproduce your error.  As it stands, none of us can reproduce your error so this will inevitably close.

Comment: rayryeng: thank you, this is yael library link:
https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=2151
in this page there are some links to download, for mac, for linux and windows.
The Yael library for linux and mac contain mex files but unfortunately there aren't any mex file in windows link.

Comment: if you download windows yael library (third link), in matlab folder, when you run make.m, mex files must create. but there are some errors for me.

Comment: Update your post - don't do it in a comment.